# list merging between list with condition in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have an output in a single list like this:

[[1, 74], [1, 224], [1, 247], [1, 5], [1, 225], [1, 207], [1, 79], [1, 131], [1, 180], [1, 20], [1, 104], [1, 93], [1, 213], [1, 93], [1, 151], [1, 223]]

[[2, 200], [2, 64], [2, 51], [2, 83], [2, 127], [2, 160], [2, 237], [2, 98], [2, 123], [2, 213], [2, 80], [2, 131], [2, 200], [2, 203], [2, 8], [2, 174]]

[[3, 148], [3, 72], [3, 37], [3, 40], [3, 237], [3, 24], [3, 177], [3, 205], [3, 52], [3, 53], [3, 155], [3, 208], [3, 184], [3, 44], [3, 202], [3, 171]]

but i want to make the output become:

[[1,74],[2,200],[3,148]]

[[1,224],[2,64],[3,72]]

[[1,247],[2,51],[3,37]]

and so on...

is it by mapping? or just looping then append?
please help me with code

Comment: Help you with what code?  You haven't posted any.

Comment: This isn't puzzling.stackexchange.com, you should describe that "condition" and how you're "merging".

Comment: You say "single list" but you actually show three.

Comment: Seems like an **un**conditional regular zip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your list lengths are equal for all three lists. Because you shared so.

```
list1 = [[1, 74], [1, 224], [1, 247], [1, 5], [1, 225], [1, 207], [1, 79], [1, 131], [1, 180], [1, 20], [1, 104], [1, 93], [1, 213], [1, 93], [1, 151], [1, 223]]

list2 = [[2, 200], [2, 64], [2, 51], [2, 83], [2, 127], [2, 160], [2, 237], [2, 98], [2, 123], [2, 213], [2, 80], [2, 131], [2, 200], [2, 203], [2, 8], [2, 174]]

list3 = [[3, 148], [3, 72], [3, 37], [3, 40], [3, 237], [3, 24], [3, 177], [3, 205], [3, 52], [3, 53], [3, 155], [3, 208], [3, 184], [3, 44], [3, 202], [3, 171]]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print([list1[i],list2[i],list3[i]])
```

For the basic level, you can use the code above.